# Value error: View didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

```
def editProfilePage(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
    form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('profile')
    else:
        return render(request,'editProfile.html', {'form':form})
        form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request,'editProfile.html', context)
```

here is the output of the terminal

the error is given below

in check_response raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view account.views.editProfilePage didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: I've indented your code properly. Now you can try again.

Comment: Pass the form directly...         return render(request,'editProfile.html', {'form': form})

Answer (score 0):

there is more than one thingh wrong here, try:

```
def editProfilePage(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request,'editProfile.html', context)
    else:
        form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request,'editProfile.html', context)
```